# axios.get first time response is empty using useState and useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I dont know why first time response is empty, I have tried several ways, using `loading` and without , using `...` thing also. can someone help me out what am I doing wrong ? No idea even why I get console 2 or 3 times even [here is my  console][1]

````
    const Product = (props) => {
        const artikeId = props.match.params['number'];
        const [productData, setProductData] = useState([]);`enter code here`
        const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

        useEffect( () => {
            const fetchData = async () => {
                await axios.get(`http://localhost:8081/products/${artikeId}`)
                    .then(res => {
                        setProductData(res.data)
                        setLoading(true)
                        //    setProductData([...productData,res.data]);
                    })
            };
            fetchData();
        }, []);

        console.log(productData)

        return <div>
If it works I will return {productData[0].name} etc etc
        </div>
    }
    export default Product```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/U58JI.png
````

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova I had thsi issue long time ago and I dont know how I fixed earlier, lets see if someone can share experience

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova , problem is first time I get empty response which means I don't get data to do anything with,

Comment: maybe yes, but can you inform me how can I do

Answer (score 0):

So first, make sure the props doesn't make the  rerender. Try to use React.memo to wrap this component.

And if you are sure that the component didn't rerender, you could use ref to simply and directly make sure loading is working.

```
const loading = useRef(false);
...
loading.current = true; // when loading
...
if (!loading.current) { // judge loading status
  ...
  loading.current = false;
}
```